# Integrating SignalR with existing WebAPI endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, push-notification, signalr, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API endpoint that creates a record and emits a successful 201 Created when the record is created.

Is it possible send a notification to a standalone HTML/JS web page that the record is created as it gets created using SignalR?

How can I create this publisher in the Web API and how to subscribe to it from the standalone webpage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - it is possible so long as that browser has an active connection to the SignalR Hub.

You can use this code as a starting point. It assumes you have a SignalR Hub class named `MessageHub`. This broadcasts a message to `all active SignalR clients`.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/messaging")]
public class MessagingController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    public void Post(Message message)
    {
        var notificationHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MessageHub>();
        if (notificationHub != null)
        {
            try
            { 
               // create your record   
               notificationHub.Clients.All.creationSuccess(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              // do a thing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`creationSuccess` is the name of the function on the client side (JavaScript) which will handle the notification inside of the browser to which you're referring.  [Here's more information regarding the details of that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client)